# How to access image files outside WAR file

Tags: war, relative-path, absolute-path

Actually, I am trying to access images, which are outside the WAR file. The images fold was in the WAR file, I am tired about building and deploy my project when adding a new image in it. So I try to put all the images in a external folder (outside WAR file). After I did that I found only IE can find the images and display it. For chrome and firefox they do not work. Please help me solve this issue.

I use relative path before. Right now, I am using absolute path like c:/xxx.jpg.
I want to display the images in jsp file.
I do not want to use CMS tool to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I should serve the files/folder in the server----config the path (tell server the path/directory you want to server) in the server configuration file (I use Jboss). Then it can be accessed